# Why it is possible to do the assignment within the for?

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippet, that I do not understand:

```
  def stream[F[_]: ConcurrentEffect](implicit T: Timer[F], C: ContextShift[F]): Stream[F, Nothing] = {
    for {
      client <- BlazeClientBuilder[F](global).stream
      helloWorldAlg = HelloWorld.impl[F]
      jokeAlg = Jokes.impl[F](client)

      // Combine Service Routes into an HttpApp.
      // Can also be done via a Router if you
      // want to extract a segments not checked
      // in the underlying routes.
      httpApp = (
        UsersvcRoutes.helloWorldRoutes[F](helloWorldAlg) <+>
          UsersvcRoutes.jokeRoutes[F](jokeAlg)
        ).orNotFound

      // With Middlewares in place
      finalHttpApp = Logger.httpApp(true, true)(httpApp)

      exitCode <- BlazeServerBuilder[F](global)
        .bindHttp(8080, "0.0.0.0")
        .withHttpApp(finalHttpApp)
        .serve
    } yield exitCode
  }.drain
```

Why it is possible to do the assignment within `for`, for example:

```
helloWorldAlg = HelloWorld.impl[F]
```

Comment: Why it won't be possible? It is just translated to a `map`. You do not need all that to test, you can do a simple `for { x <- List(1, 2, 3); y = x * 2 } yield y` and it just works. Or I am missing something of the question?

Comment: I am not confident with Scala and did not know, that I can write in that way.

Comment: This may help: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is best explained with many examples

```
for { 
  x <- List(1, 2, 3)
  y = x * 2 
} yield y
```

desugars to

```
List(1, 2, 3)
  .map { x =>
    val y = x * 2
    (x, y)         // note the Tuple2
  }
  .map { case (x, y) => y }
```

whilst

```
for {
  x <- List(1, 2, 3)
  y = x * 2
  z = x * 3
} yield y
```

desugars to

```
List(1, 2, 3)
  .map { x =>
    val y = x * 2
    val z = x * 3
    (x, y, z)       // note the Tuple3
  }
  .map { case (x, y, z) => y }
```

whilst

```
for {
  x <- List(1, 2, 3)
  y = x * 2
  i <- List(4, 5, 6)
  z = x * 3
} yield y
```

desugars to

```
List(1, 2, 3)
  .map { x =>
    val y = x * 2
    (x, y)         // note the Tuple2
  }
  .flatMap { case (x, y) =>
    List(4, 5, 6)
      .map { i =>
        val z = x * 3
        (i, z)     // note the Tuple2
      }
      .map { case (i, z) => y }
  }
```

We see a pattern when generator `p <- e` is followed by value definition `p' = e'`, then a [tuple](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) `(p, p')` is passed along the chain.